# Error - Setup Heroku environment with Dart Buildpacks

Tags: heroku, telegram-bot

I tried to create an app using this command:

```
heroku create — buildpack https://github.com/stablekernel/heroku-buildpack-dart.git
```

But I get an error:

```
Creating ⬢ https://github.com/stablekernel/heroku-buildpack-dart.git... !
 !    Name must start with a letter, end with a letter or digit and can only contain lowercase letters, digits, and
 !    dashes. Name is too long (maximum is 30 characters)
```

How can I solve this?

I amy trying to build my own Telegram bot.

Reference:
https://medium.com/@viceconti.federico/how-to-deploy-your-telegram-bot-on-heroku-with-teledart-6ee197c0df91

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with writing programming blogs on platforms that aren't meant for code is that they sometimes reformat things in an attempt to be helpful.

The command shouldn't be

```
heroku create — buildpack https://github.com/stablekernel/heroku-buildpack-dart.git
```

but rather

```
heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/stablekernel/heroku-buildpack-dart.git
```

Note the `--buildpack`, where `--` indicates an option for the `heroku` CLI.